# One User to many domains using Grails and Spring Security Core

Tags: jakarta-ee, grails, spring-security

I'm trying to implement Admin Panel to manage few domains. Functional requirement is that only admin can add new Users.

I decided to implement Admin Panel as separate application connected to the same Database (which is MySQL) and move all admin's activities to this Panel.

Everything looks fine, content and subpages are available to both domains, but the problem is with Users. I created admin in BootStrap class in AdminPanel, User is saved in DB, I can login to Admin Panel, but I **CAN'T**  login to second domain.

I found that Spring Security Core created column  **class** in table of users and I think this is the problem:

```
+----+----------+-----------------+
| id | username | class           |
+----+----------+-----------------+
|  1 | admin    | adminpanel.User |
+----+----------+-----------------+
```

I can't change it manually, 'cause one User should be able to login to few domains (separate applications) managed by the admin (admin decide i.a. which domain**s** are accessible for user).

Finally the question is: How to solve this problem? How to make user's login action independent from application where his account has been created?

Comment: What version of Spring Security Core plugin are you using?

Comment: spring-security-core:1.2.7.3
In act of desperation I've already given the same package name for User domain class in both apps, but I don't think it's proper solution.